# Repeating message, but shouldn't repeat this message in Task

Tags: c#, macos, tcp, server, listener

[image: problem]
See the problem in the picture. The Server starts a new Task for accepting the clients and then handles it in the function Handle(client), this all works fine, but it every time it repeats this one message "Client connecting...", but it shouldn't. Nothing else of the Task is called but this message. And the bool Pending() is false, so it shouldn't start another Task.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebServer
{
    class WebServer
    {
        public static WebServer Server { get; private set; }

        private TcpListener _tcpListener = null;
        public CancellationTokenSource TokenSource { get; private set; }
        public CancellationToken Token { get; private set; }

        public int i = 0;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WebServer.Server = new WebServer();
        }

        WebServer()
        {
            IPAddress ipAddress;

            try
            {
                ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
            } catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error while parsing ip address: " + e.Message);
                return;
            }

            _tcpListener = new TcpListener(ipAddress, 8080);
            _tcpListener.Start();

            TokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            Token = TokenSource.Token;

            //Execute server
            Task.Run(() => Run());

            Console.ReadKey();
            TokenSource.Cancel();

            WaitHandle handle = Token.WaitHandle;
            handle.WaitOne();
        }

        private void Run()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Server is runnning");
            while(!Token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                if(_tcpListener.Pending())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Pending: " + _tcpListener.Pending());
                    Task.Run(() => {
                        Console.WriteLine("Client connecting...");
                        TcpClient client = _tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();

                        this.Handle(client);
                        return;
                    });
                }
            }
        }

        private void Handle(TcpClient client)
        {
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

            Console.WriteLine("Handling....");

            while(client.Connected)
            {
                if(stream.DataAvailable)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Start Reading...");
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    stream.Read(buffer, 0, 1024);
                    Console.WriteLine("Read: " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer));
                }

                client.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Client connecting shouldn't repeat every time, everything else works

Comment: I am on mobile so I have not tested any code but you have and infinite loop at while(!Token), when you get your first TCPClient, if(_tcp...) will be true, and you will enqueue a task into threadpool. I can not stress enough that the task has not started processing on threadpool, yet. By the time, it starts processing, pending will be true in an infinite loop and you will enqueue so many tasks into threadpool but only one of the tasks will call Handle method( assuming you have a single client) because AcceptTCPClient() is a blocking method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emrah Süngü's comments seem accurate and correct

```
TcpClient client = _tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient(); // accept first
Console.WriteLine("Client connecting...");

// then start processing in your task
Task.Run(() => this.Handle(client));
```

It makes perfect sense when you think about it, you are in a while loop, and you are starting several tasks before the code to except the client actually runs.

***Disclaimer*** : This is totally untested and i am not responsible for and harm you cause to others or your self with this code :)

Comment: another nice hat you got there!

Comment: @EmrahSüngü its a lovely hat! :P